# How to increase no. of divisions on x-axis in matlab

Tags: arrays

I want to increase the number of divisions on x-axis in matlab. I have used XTick but its not working..Actually I want a resolution of 0.001, but its giving a resolution of 0.1 which was the same without using XTick.  My range of x-axis is from 0.6 to 0.7 and result is displayed in the steps of 0.1 as 0.6,0.61,0.62,0.63 and so on till 0.7. I want these values as 0.601,0.602,0.603 and so on on x-axis.What to do?Please reply

Answer (score 0):

use

```
set(gca,'XTick',tickVector);
```

`tickVector` is  tick positions